# FindRoot errors

Tags: equation-solving, machine-precision

I'm trying to solve a system of two equations in two variables for some range of parameter values. I use `ContourPlot` to see where I should look for a solutions and then I use `FindRoot` to get the solutions. However, I am getting some "you need more than machine precision.." errors and sometimes when I rescale the function the error goes away. But I never thought to plug the solution back into the main expression to confirm that I get 0 until a few moments back and unfortunately I am not getting zeros.

My function is hyper sensitive to the values and the solutions I get from this `FindRoot` I want to use to compute other things later. So I am worried about picking up non-solutions. What are some good practices I can use in these conditions? How can I ensure that I do have a solution? Is `ContourPlot` reliable in terms of where to look?

Here is the exact problem I am solving:

My parameter is `c0`. I am looking to solve the system for "small" `c0`. The example below has `c0=0.004` and I am looking to see how small I could push it between `0.01 > c0 >0.0001`

The variables I am solving for are `H0S` and `H0D`.

```
 f1 = (-1.906273202485612` + 891.8237204611049` c0) H0D^1.7049946543060779` -    10.246354837464178` H0D^1.8549946543060778` - 0.3513303329336004` H0D^2.704994654306078` + (50.83395206628298` - 891.8237204611049` c0) H0S^1.7049946543060779` +   10.246354837464178` H0S^1.8549946543060778` - .0702660665867201` H0S^2.704994654306078`;

f2 = (-1.093726797514388` + 511.6850514687195` c0)/H0D^2.9716613209727445` - 6.736078957579072`/H0D^2.821661320972744` - 0.4820030003997329`/H0D^1.9716613209727445` + (   29.166047933717014` - 511.6850514687195` c0)/H0S^2.9716613209727445` + 6.736078957579072`/H0S^2.821661320972744` - 0.09640060007994662`/H0S^1.9716613209727445`;


 c0 = 0.004
 sub = 1088.96;
 slb = 1088.94;
 dub = 2.1774212*10^(-6);
 dlb = 2.177421*10^(-6);

 ContourPlot[{f1, f2}, {H0S, slb, sub}, {H0D, dlb, dub}]
```

This is what the `ContourPlot` looks like:

[image]

Then I try to find solutions:

```
{hs, hd, c0} = {H0S, H0D, c0} /. FindRoot[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0}, {H0S, (slb + sub)/2, slb, 
sub}, {H0D, (dlb + dub)/2, dlb, dub}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

{1088.95, 2.17742*10^-6, 0.004}

Scale1 = f1 /. {H0S -> 2000, H0D -> 0.000001};
Scale2 = f2 /. {H0S -> 2000, H0D -> 0.000001};

{hs, hd, c0} = {H0S, H0D, c0} /. FindRoot[{(f1)/Scale1 == 0, (f2)/Scale2 == 0}, {H0S, (slb + sub)/2, 
slb, sub}, {H0D, (dlb + dub)/2, dlb, dub}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

{1088.95, 2.17742*10^-6, 0.004}
```

When I do `FindRoot` without the scale, I get an error message about "..more than machine precision.." but when I do the `FindRoot` with the scale then I don't get any errors. But the solutions are the same.

However, when I do this:

```
  f1 /. {H0S -> hs, H0D -> hd}
  f2 /. {H0S -> hs, H0D -> hd}
  (f1/Scale1) /. {H0S -> hs, H0D -> hd}
  (f2/Scale2) /. {H0S -> hs, H0D -> hd}
```

I get:

```
4.6912*10^-11
-15.7874
-1.80356*10^-18
-2.22429*10^-16
```

My `f2=-15` at the proposed solution. So what's going on? Can I reliably use this solution going forward? How do I get it to give me the solution that makes `f1` and `f2` small..like zero... the solution `ContourPlot` seems to indicate that exists.

**EDIT to include problems with**  ``Rationalize`and`Rationalize[..,0]`

```
fa=-1.90627 H0D^1.70499 + 52.3946 f H0D^1.70499 - 10.2464 H0D^1.85499 -0.35133 H0D^2.70499 + 11.1478 f H0S^1.70499 + 10.2464 H0S^1.85499 - 0.0702661 H0S^2.70499 + (0.523946 (9. + 100. f - 1. H0D) H0D^1.70499 H0S^1.70499 (877653. - 1. H0S^2.97166) (877653. - 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))/((-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653. H0S^1.70499 - 1. H0S^4.67666 + H0D^4.67666 (1 - 0.000389055 H0S^1.70499) + H0D^1.70499 (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))) + (0.523946 (9. + 100. f - 1. H0D) H0D^3.40999 (877653. - 
1. H0S^2.97166) (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))/((-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653. H0S^1.70499 - 1. H0S^4.67666 + H0D^4.67666 (1 - 0.000389055 H0S^1.70499) + 
H0D^1.70499 (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666)))

fb=    (30.0615 f)/H0D^2.97166 - 1.09373/H0D^2.97166 + (-0.857219 - 
  0.280427 H0D^0.85)/H0D^2.82166 - 5.87886/H0D^2.82166 - \
0.201576/H0D^1.97166 + (6.39606 f)/H0S^2.97166 + (
 0.857219 - 
  0.0560854 H0S^0.85)/H0S^2.82166 + 5.87886/H0S^2.82166 - \
0.0403152/H0S^1.97166 + (
 0.300615 (9. + 100. f - 1. H0D) (877653. - 
 1. H0S^2.97166) (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))/(
 H0D^1.26667 (-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653. H0S^1.70499 - 
   1. H0S^4.67666 + H0D^4.67666 (1 - 0.000389055 H0S^1.70499) + 
   H0D^1.70499 (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))) - (
 0.300615 (9. + 100. f - 1. H0D) H0D^1.70499 (877653. - 
  1. H0S^2.97166) (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666))/(
 H0S^2.97166 (-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653. H0S^1.70499 - 
  1. H0S^4.67666 + H0D^4.67666 (1 - 0.000389055 H0S^1.70499) + 
  H0D^1.70499 (-877653. + 0.000389055 H0S^4.67666)))

f = 0.3
ContourPlot[{fa == 0, fb == 0}, {H0S, 405, 408}, {H0D, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]

According to `ContourPlot` the solution is near `(406,1.50)`

```
far = Rationalize[fa, 10^-16];
fbr = Rationalize[fa, 10^-16];
fa0 = Rationalize[fa, 0];
fb0 = Rationalize[fa, 0];
Clear[f]

 In[21]:= {hsr, hdr} = {H0S, H0D} /. 
  FindRoot[{far == 0, fbr == 0} /. {f -> 0.3}, {H0S, 410, 360.5, 
    420}, {H0D, 1, 0.0001, 5}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

Out[21]= {406.678, 0.316565}

In[434]:= {hs, hd} = {H0S, H0D} /.FindRoot[{fa == 0, fb == 0} /. {f -> 0.3}, {H0S, 400,    360.5, 420}, {H0D, 1, 0.0001, 5}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

Out[434]= {406.43, 1.54421}


In[12]:= {hs0, hd0} = {H0S, H0D} /. 
 FindRoot[{fa0 == 0, fb0 == 0} /. {f -> 0.3}, {H0S, 400, 360.5, 
 420}, {H0D, 1, 0.0001, 5}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]

Out[12]= {406.175, 2.32183}
```

The solutions I get using rationalize are clearly incorrect if `ContourPlot` is to be believed. Now I will substitute these solutions in the expression below:

```
 exp=117.218 - 1754.39 f (0.047 + (0.00047 (9. + 100 f - H0D) (877653. - 
   H0S^2.97166) (-(877653./H0S^1.70499) + 0.000389055 H0S^2.97166))/(f (-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653./H0D^1.70499 - 0.000389055 H0D^2.97166 - 877653./H0S^1.70499 + H0D^2.97166/H0S^1.70499 + 0.000389055 H0S^2.97166 - H0S^2.97166/
   H0D^1.70499))) + 877653. ((30.0615 f)/H0D^2.97166 - (0.336512 (0.833333 + 2.54737/H0D^0.85))/H0D^1.97166 - (0.122684 (2.97166 (3. + 16.9824 H0D^0.15 +          0.833333 H0D) H0D^1.97166 - (0.833333 + 2.54737/H0D^0.85) H0D^2.97166))/H0D^4.94332 + (
0.300615 (9. + 100 f - H0D) (877653. - H0S^2.97166) (-(877653./H0S^1.70499) + 
   0.000389055 H0S^2.97166))/(H0D^2.97166 (-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653./H0D^1.70499 - 0.000389055 H0D^2.97166 - 877653./H0S^1.70499 + H0D^2.97166/H0S^1.70499 + 0.000389055 H0S^2.97166 - H0S^2.97166/H0D^1.70499))) + 0.000389055 (52.3946 f H0D^1.70499 - (    0.213828 (2.97166 (3. + 16.9824 H0D^0.15 + 0.833333 H0D) H0D^1.97166 - (0.833333 + 2.54737/
      H0D^0.85) H0D^2.97166))/H0D^0.266667 + (0.523946 (9. + 100 f - H0D) H0D^1.70499 (877653. - H0S^2.97166) (-(877653./H0S^1.70499) + 0.000389055 H0S^2.97166))/((-877653. + H0S^2.97166) (877653./H0D^1.70499 - 0.000389055 H0D^2.97166 - 877653./H0S^1.70499 + 
   H0D^2.97166/H0S^1.70499 + 0.000389055 H0S^2.97166 - H0S^2.97166/H0D^1.70499)))




In[22]:= exp /. {H0S -> hs, H0D -> hd, f -> 0.3}
         exp /. {H0S -> hs0, H0D -> hd0, f -> 0.3}
         exp /. {H0S -> hsr, H0D -> hdr, f -> 0.3}

Out[22]= 99.0462

Out[23]= -58748.5

 Out[24]= 5.63457*10^7
```

99 is around where the answer should be whereas -58752 and 5*10^7 are just absurdly wrong. This is making me real hesitant about using `Rationalize`. At least in this instance I knew what the answer was gonna look like. For many other expressions I don't have a good idea and I could introduce errors and things could go wildly wrong as the errors compound.

Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13947/nsolve-gives-additional-solutions-that-dont-satisfy-the-equations) somewhat help you?

Comment: If you had read the link and all the comments below carefully, you should have noticed that what you need isn't `Rationalize[…, 10^-16]` but `Rationalize[…, 0]` for your 2nd sample; `SetPrecision[…, Infinity]` will also work. BTW I really suggest you to clean up your sample a little (your 2nd sample is not even available for direct running! ) so it can attract more attention.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. I'll follow up on `Rationalize[..,0]`. Also, sorry about the example, I will correct it. I must've made a mistake after pasting it while I was pressing back space and delete to get the pasted stuff four spaces away from the margin.

Comment: @xzczd I used `Rationalize[..,0]` in my second example and the solution I am getting is incorrect and is giving me absurd answers when I use it to compute other variables. It also contradicts what I see in `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that a higher `WorkingPrecision` (for example 20) in `FindRoot` is still needed, and the option `MaxIterations` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a fully satisfactorily solution but more of a starting point. The problem is the function `f2` because of the negative powers; if one stays away from zeros then you can try to factor them out.

```
(* Made the interval a bit wider *)
c0 = 0.004
sub = 1090;
slb = 1088;
dub = 2.178 10^(-6);
dlb = 2.177 10^(-6);

powerH0D = Cases[f2, Power[H0D, p_] -> p , 2];
powerH0S = Cases[f2, Power[H0S, p_] -> p , 2];

badFactor = Power[H0D, Min[powerH0D]] Power[H0S, Min[powerH0S]];

f2new = f2/badFactor // Expand ;

sol = FindRoot[{(f1 /. num_Real :> SetPrecision[num, \[Infinity]]) == 0, 
                (f2 /. num_Real :> SetPrecision[num, \[Infinity]]) == 0},    
   {H0S, (slb + sub)/2, slb, sub}, {H0D, (dlb + dub)/2, dlb, dub},  
   MaxIterations -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 40];

{f1, f2new} /. sol
(* {4.6912*10^-11, 1.20205*10^-7} *)

{f1, f2} /. sol
(* {4.6912*10^-11, 0.212433} *)
```

Comment: ok cool. so is the idea that `f2(x)=good(x)*bad(x)` then if `bad(a)!=Infinity` and `good(a)=0` then `a` is a solution to `f2` ? In my example, `badFactor/.sol` is around `10^16`.. can we say that that's not (or not going to) Infinity?

Comment: As long as neither of `sol` is 0 then yes, `badFactor` is finite (but possibly very large).

Comment: ...phbbhtt.. my brains are fried. Ocfcourse.. I *know* what badFactor is.. literally ... I can't believe I asked the second part of the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `Rationalize` on your equations first

```
f1r = Rationalize[f1, 10^-16];
f2r = Rationalize[f2, 10^-16];
```

and then use a higher `WorkingPrecision`

```
fr = FindRoot[{f1r == 0, f2r == 0}, {H0S, (slb + sub)/2,slb,sub}, 
              {H0D, (dlb + dub)/2, dlb, dub}, MaxIterations -> Infinity, 
              WorkingPrecision -> 32];
```

The results should be better:

```
f1r /. fr
(*0.*10^-25*)
f2r /. fr
(*0.*10^-15*)
```

Does that help?

Comment: I just now realized this is basically the same as Daniel suggests in the answer @xzczd linked to...

Comment: @sebhofer... that's pretty cool. I'm trying to read Daniel's answer but since it has details of the other question, it is not immediately clear to me why `Rationalize` reduces any numerical instability or other issues. If you can expand a bit on why `Rationalize` works then that would be awesome Thanks

Comment: @sebhofer Try `{f1, f2} /. fr` though.

Comment: @b.gatessucks whoa.. I got `{-3.67838*10^-9, 208.209}` when I tried `{f1, f2} /. fr`. Whats going on?

Comment: Just what you said yourself, your function is hyper sensitive. A very good solution to a slightly changed `f2` is not a good solution for the original function.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I don't think you can deduce that from your observation. I guess that the discrepancy is caused by floating-point arithmetic. The point is that `f1r` and `f2r` are the same as `f1` and `f2` up to errors which are smaller than `MachinePrecision`. However, manipulation of the rationalized functions does not involve floating-point arithmetic and is thus exact.

Comment: 囧…after changing the `Rationalize[…, 0]` in sebhofer's code into `SetPrecison[…, Infinity]`, I get the correct result as @b.gatessucks … I don't know the exact reason though…

Comment: BTW, I found that the option `MaxIterations` isn't necessary here and we only need `WorkingPrecision -> 9` for this case.

Comment: @xzczd That's an interesting observation. I wonder why `Rationalize` and `SetPrecision` behave differently in this case. However I find that I need a `WorkingPrecision` of at least 20 to get decent accuracy for the result. A value of 9 is even less then `MachinePrecision`, so I don't understand how that should work out. (Btw for WP equal to 9, Mathematica even displays a warning about no significant digits!)

Comment: @sebhofer Er…maybe I forgot to `Clear` the variables or just mistook the result yesterday, I tried the code again and this time `WorkingPrecision -> 17` is needed: though the output for `f2r` is framed by a red box (what's the exact meaning of it?), `{f1, f2}` is OK. And to avoid the red box, `WorkingPrecision -> 19` is enough.

Comment: And I found that the documentation has already given a explanation for `SetPrecision[…, 0]` and `Rationalize[…, Infinity]`, not difficult to understand. A somewhat related question is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14122/deletecases-messing-with-my-mind). At last, let me give the same sigh as @b.gatessucks : this function is so sensitive!

Comment: @sebhofer `Rationalize` is not working out for me. Even though I am getting solutions, when I substitute the solutions into expressions whose values I have a good idea about I am getting non-sense answers. I can post the example in my question.