# NDSolve problems of convergence

Tags: differential-equations

I have a big function that I have to maximize, so I have to evaluate some equation with thousands of different values of the parameter.
But the FindMaximum returns me many errors. 
I have traced the cause down to a differential equation that is part of the calculation. 
This differential equation has to be solved as function of the parameter (called "sup" in this case) and even though it is a seemingly "easy" function and I don't need a very high precision, in many points it does not converge and reaches the maximum number of steps.
The following is a simplified sample code to view the problem with a Manipulate: as you slide the cursor with the Sup variable the NDsolve produces errors.

```
     Manipulate[
 Module[{pend, tmax}, tmax = 30; 
  pend = NDSolve[{1.1089 α''[t] + 1.2936 Sin[α[t]] + 
       210*sup*
        (0.33 Sin[α[t]] + (
          0.33^2 Cos[α[t]] Sin[α[t]])/Sqrt[
          1 - 0.33^2 Sin[α[t]]^2]) *
        UnitStep[Sin[α[t] + Pi*UnitStep[-α'[t]]]] == 
      0, α[0] == -Pi/3, α'[0] == 0}, α, {t, 0, 
     tmax}, MaxSteps -> 10^5, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
    AccuracyGoal -> acc]; 
  Plot[α[x] /. pend, {x, 0, tmax}]], {{sup, 0.01, "Sup"}, 0.01,
   0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{acc, 8, "Acc"}, 6, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Bookmarks -> {
   "Error1" :> {sup = 0.0577, acc = 7}, 
   "Error2" :> {sup = 0.0413, acc = 8}, 
   "Error3" :> {sup = 0.0351, acc = 6}}]
```

I have tried with increasing the MaxSteps and reducing the AccuracyGoal/PrecisionGoal, but it seems that there are always points in which the NDSolve does not return a good solution. 
And thus I cannot execute the FindMaximum to maximize my function.

Any hint on how to avoid this kind of problem and get NDSolve to return a correct result? 
Is there a way to trace down why NDSolve has this problems of convergence with this function?

Thanks for any help,

JBB

PD: Code update to define tmax. In the manipulate Bookmarks I have placed some examples of errors.

Comment: It works without problems for me.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, tmax is undefined in this sample code, so it gives the error you show. I correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a "dirty" patch that I'm using and I leave here in case it is of use to someone else.
Augmenting the WorkingPrecision is a good solution but makes the program extremely slow, thanks to xzczd in any case.

So I'm using some "knowledge" of the function:

- I know that the function is a decreasing oscillation and if it "shoots up" it is because of an integration problem, but not a real data,
- and also as I don't need a very high precision

What I do is to detect that there has been an integration problem (because the integration time does not reach the specified one) and if this is the case, then change a little bit the input parameter and repeat the integration until I get a "good" solution.
It's not an elegant solution, but it works for me.

Here is the code:

```
    Module[{pend, tmax, supTemp},
 Manipulate[
  supTemp = sup;
  Label[repeatChangingSup]; (*If NDSolve has errors returns here and \
tries again with a slightly different surface *)
  tmax = 100;
  pend = Quiet@
    NDSolve[{1.1089 α''[t] + 1.2936 Sin[α[t]] + 
        210*supTemp*
         (0.33 Sin[α[t]] + (
           0.33^2 Cos[α[t]] Sin[α[t]])/Sqrt[
           1 - 0.33^2 Sin[α[t]]^2]) *
         UnitStep[Sin[α[t] + Pi*UnitStep[-α'[t]]]] == 
       0, α[0] == -Pi/3, α'[0] == 0}, α, {t, 0, 
      tmax}];
  If[tmax == pend[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[2]],(* 
   If tmax is the same as the last value of the interp function, 
   the NDSolve has finished succesfully*)
   pend, (*if everything OK return pend*)
   supTemp = supTemp*1.0001; Print[supTemp]; 
   Goto[repeatChangingSup];]; (* 
  Else there was an error in NDSolve and we try with a sligthly \
different sup *)
  Plot[α[x] /. pend, {x, 0, tmax}],
  {{sup, 0.01, "Sup"}, 0.01, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A higher `WorkingPrecison` will somewhat help:

```
Manipulate[Module[{pend, tmax}, tmax = 30;
  pend = Quiet@
    NDSolve[{1.1089 α''[t] + 1.2936 Sin[α[t]] + 
        210*sup*(0.33 Sin[α[
              t]] + (0.33^2 Cos[α[t]] Sin[α[t]])/
            Sqrt[1 - 0.33^2 Sin[α[t]]^2])*
         UnitStep[Sin[α[t] + Pi*UnitStep[-α'[t]]]] == 
       0, α[0] == -Pi/3, α'[0] == 0}, α, {t, 0, 
      tmax}, MaxSteps -> 10^5, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
     AccuracyGoal -> acc, WorkingPrecision -> 32];
  Plot[α[x] /. pend, {x, 0, tmax}]], {{sup, 0.01, "Sup"}, 0.01,
   0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{acc, 8, "Acc"}, 6, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Bookmarks -> {"Error1" :> {sup = 0.0577, acc = 7}, 
   "Error2" :> {sup = 0.0413, acc = 8}, 
   "Error3" :> {sup = 0.0351, acc = 6}}]
```

Notice that here I use `Quiet` to quit the warning message because the warning generates just for those decimates (their `Precision`s are `MachinePrecision`) in the equation and it doesn't influence the result. If the equation isn't in `Manipulate` you can also `Rationalize` all the decimates in the equation to avoid the warning.

For more information about the reason why I change `WorkingPrecision`, you can have a look at the following questions (there may be more, but at the moment I just remember these):

[ReplaceAll[] and Limit[] don't give correct results for this expression under extreme variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/replaceall-and-limit-dont-give-correct-results-for-this-expression-under-ex)

[Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients)

[FindRoot errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14264/findroot-errors)

[NSolve gives additional solutions that don't satisfy the equations!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13947/nsolve-gives-additional-solutions-that-dont-satisfy-the-equations)