# FindMaxValue specifics

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm using `FindMaxValue` to study the distribution of maxima of `Abs[RiemannSiegelZ[t]]` between consecutive values of `ZetaZero`,

Some background:  `RiemannSiegelZ[t]` is `Zeta[1/2+I* t]` 'with the phase taken out'; i.e. real for real $t$ and with the same absolute value as `Zeta`.  Outside of *Mathematica* this is known as Hardy's function $Z(t)$.  On the Riemann Hypothesis, $Z(t)$ has no positive local minima or negative local maxima 'for $t$ sufficiently large'  (see Edwards' book "Riemann's Zeta Function".)  In fact $t>5$ is sufficient.  Thus on the Riemann Hypothesis $Z(t)$ is positive (resp. negative) and concave down (resp. up) with a unique local maximum (resp. minimum) for $t$ between `ZetaZero[2k-1]` and `ZetaZero[2k]` (resp `ZetaZero[2k]` and `ZetaZero[2k+1]`).

To determine the maxima, I'm less concerned with speed or precision than I am with robustness.  The documentation says that

> `FindMaxValue[f,{x, x0, x1}]` searches for a local maximum in `f` using `x0` and `x1` as the first two values of x, avoiding the use of derivatives.

Is this routine *guaranteed* to return a value between `x0` and `x1` if there is in fact a unique local maximum there (i.e., guaranteed to not jump outside the interval)?  Should I be using a `Method` other than `Automatic`, and if so, which one?

The documentation also says:

> `FindMaxValue[f,{x, x0, xmin, xmax}]` searches for a local maximum, stopping the search if `x` ever gets outside the range `xmin` to `xmax`.

It does not say what the parameter `x0` determines but from earlier documentation one would suppose that it is the starting point for the search.  What does it mean if the search 'stops'?  Does *Mathematica* return an error message?

What is the difference between

```
FindMaxValue[f,{x, x0, xmin, xmax}]
```

and

```
FindMaxValue[{f, xmin < x < xmax}, {x, x0}]
```

Finally, I'm having difficulties with (I think) the fact that `FindMaxValue` has the attribute `HoldAll`, for example

```
In[3]:= t1 = N[Im[ZetaZero[1]]]; t2 = 
 N[Im[ZetaZero[2]]]; tmid = (t1 + t2)/2; FindMaxValue[
 RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, tmid, t1, t2}]

FindMaxValue::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {t} = {17.8742}. >>

Out[3]= 2.31595
```

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in v8, but with v9 I get a 'clean' answer of `2.3405510299088133`

Comment: I'll upgrade to 9 if that's required.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: For the last part of the question, it's another story of precision. Try this: `t1 = N[Im[ZetaZero[1]], 8]; t2 = 
 N[Im[ZetaZero[2]], 8]; tmid = (t1 + t2)/2; FindMaxValue[
 RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, tmid, t1, t2}, WorkingPrecision -> 8]`

Comment: @xzczd:  OK, that fixes it, Thanks!  But why not a more helpful error message?

Comment: The error is caused by `MachinePrecision` indirectly. _Mathematica_ doesn't give warnings for the mistake caused by `MachinePrecision`. You can check the document, and for more information, have a look at the links I pasted in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16823/1871).

Comment: Dumb question: why not use the Gram points as starting values for `FindMaxValue[]` (okay, apart from some of the Gram points not actually being near the extrema of $Z(t)$...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this routine guaranteed to return a value between `x0` and `x1` if there is in fact a unique local maximum there (i.e., guaranteed to not jump outside the interval)?

Nope. Consider for instance a simple example:

```
FindArgMax[Sin[x], {x, π/2 - π/6, π/2 - π/12}]
   {1.570796326793869}
```

where we see that the known maximum at $x=\pi/2$ was found, which is of course outside the bounds given. On the other hand, look at the following:

```
FindArgMax[Sin[x], {x, 3 π/8, π/2 - π/6, π/2 - π/12}] // Quiet
   {1.3089969389957472}
```

(I had to suppress the warning message that the optimum was found at the interval's edge for this, though.) On the other hand, I would admit that I don't know if the local optimization functions retain the possibility of returning a point outside a given interval if the function being optimized looks "parabolic" within the given interval.

---

Since the derivative of `RiemannSiegelZ` looks a bit nasty (try executing `RiemannSiegelZ'`!), one can either elect to use finite differences for approximating the gradient, or using a gradient-free method altogether.

To illustrate the first approach,

```
t1 = Im[N[ZetaZero[1]]]; t2 = Im[N[ZetaZero[2]]];

FindMaximum[RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, (t1 + t2)/2, t1, t2}, 
            Gradient :> {"FiniteDifference", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}]
   {2.340551029908819, {t -> 17.882582076641626}}
```

For the second approach, the only genuinely derivative-free method that seems to be available is the "principal axis" method of Richard Brent:

```
FindMaximum[RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, (t1 + t2)/2, t1, t2},
            Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
   {2.3405510299088164, {t -> 17.88258207729408}}
```

(*Mathematica* apparently has an implementation of the genuinely univariate optimization method by Brent, but alas, it is only available for line searches. A pity.)

I have used `FindMaximum[]` here, but the same should apply to its cognate functions `FindArgMax[]` and `FindMaxValue[]`.