# Integration of a high oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to get the numerical result of the integration below:

```
Integrate[Exp[I* s*1000.0]*1/(1 + (10)^2*s^2), {s, 0, Infinity}]
(*5.8434816785318*10^-45 - 5.204153095728048*10^26 I*)
```

The result is wrong in my opinion because when the `Exp[I*...]` have a high frequency this tends to make the integral zero or finite, this is called wave rotating approximation in physics.

I tried:

```
 NIntegrate[Exp[I* s*1000.0]*1/(1 + (10)^2*s^2), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1000]

 (* lots of erros ...........
 -0.000021305291177576493 + 0.0010002002551860643 I*)
```

Because the function `1/(1 + (10)^2*s^2)` decays fast enough I think it isn't necessary to integrate up to infinity so I change it to a numerical number like 10^3, using bigger upper limits almost has no effect on the result so it's a good approximation and I consider this as the right answer:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I* s*1000.0]*1/(1 + (10)^2*s^2), {s, 0, 10^3}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1000]
(*1.1026966286690337*10^-14 + 0.0010002002470217504 I*)
```

Questions:

Why does MMA give the wrong result in the first example by using `Integrate`?

I really couldn't get the errors in the second example and I am not familiar with either `Integrate`'s options or that of `NIntegrate`. Is it possible to get the correct result when the upper bound of Integration is infinity?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is merely a matter of precision:

```
Integrate[Exp[I*s*1000]*1/(1 + 10^2*s^2), {s, 0, Infinity}]
N[%, 16]
```

> ```
> π/(20 E^100) + 1/20 I Sqrt[π] MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 2500]
> 0.*10^-45 + 0.0010002002407240688 I
> ```

If you want to use `NIntegrate`, then a quick search in the document shows that `"LevinRule"` is your friend:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*s*1000]*1/(1 + 10^2*s^2), {s, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "LevinRule"]
```

> ```
> -5.3668*10^-18 + 0.0010002 I
> ```

A little different from the result generated by `Integrate` but it's acceptable. If you add a `WorkingPrecision -> (* a number >= 16* )` then you'll get better result.

---

Regarding to the comment:

```
int[x_] = Integrate[Exp[I*s*x]*1/(1 + 10^2*s^2), {s, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
int[1000]
N[%, 16]
```

> ```
> 1/20 E^(-(Abs[x]/10)) π + 1/20 I Sqrt[π] 
>       MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, x^2/400] Sign[x]
> π/(20 E^100) + 1/20 I Sqrt[π] MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 2500]
> 5.843481678531469*10^-45 + 0.001000200240724069 I
> ```

The assumption is necessary. I'm using v9.0.1

Comment: If you change `1000`in the exponential function to something else like `x` and define a function out of it, and then put x then the result is wrong. I think MMA solves the integrate wrong when we use `Integrate`. I don't know in this case how the precision matters.

Comment: @yashar See my edit.

Comment: If I put a real number in int[1000.0], I get:
5.843481678531469*10^-45 - 3.312359715464843*10^26 I

However, int[1000] returns:
5.843481678531469*10^-45 + 0.001000200240724069 I

Comment: @yashar Yeah, that's expected result. `1000` is a number with infinity precision, while `1000.0` is a number with `MachinePrecison`. There're many posts about this issue in this site, have a search :)

Comment: Could you please give me some of those topics about this issue? I have no clue what search for.
Moreover, `Limit[int[x], x -> 1000.0]` returns 5.843481678531469*10^-45, it omits the imaginary part.

Comment: note that `MiejerG` eval breaks down dramatically if you do not request extended precision: `N[MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 2500],16]-> 0.01128`  ... `N[MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 2500]]-> -3.7376*10^27` obviously an implementation bug, er.. limitation.

Comment: @yashar A bit of algebra leads to the exponential integral: `Exp[I*s*1000]*Apart[1/(1 + (10)^2*s^2) /. s -> u/I] /. u -> I s`. Expand and integrate each part. Use exact coefficients as @xzczd recommends above. Numerically it is better behaved.  As for `N[expr]` vs `N[expr, prec]`: The first does machine precision **quickly** without precision tracking, and the second tracks the precision and ensures an accurate result. The first way, depending on the algorithm, can accumulate a lot of error.

Comment: @yashar Just search _MachinePrecision_ and _WorkingPrecision_, and you'll see lots of posts about how and why precision dramatically influence the result. I used to collect just 4 of them [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16823/1871).

Comment: @MichaelE2 is this "quickly" concept documented. I can see no indication that  `N[expr]` should differ (in this case wildly) from `N[expr,$MachinePrecision]`

Comment: @george2079 "The main advantage of using the built-in floating-point capabilities of your computer is speed." From [`tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html); see also [`tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html).  Try timing `N` on `expr = Sin[Range[10^5]]`; the `$MachinePrecision` calculation takes about 25 times longer.  Also compare the number of digits in `FullForm` and `ByteCount` of `N[Sin[1]]` with those of `N[Sin[1], $MachinePrecision]`.